# Copy database from one server to another using c#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database

I'm trying to create a windows application that copies a database from one server to another using the Transfer object
but end up having "The Integration Services component is not installed or you do not have permission to use it" error. 
both servers have enterprise edition of sql server 2005 and the integration services component installed, the connection logins have full permissions as well. I really don't know what goes wrong here

```
            Server backFromServer = new Server(@"xx.xx.xx.xx");
            Server backToServer = new Server(@"xx.xx.xx.xx");
            backFromServer.ConnectionContext.LoginSecure = false;
            backFromServer.ConnectionContext.Login = "username";
            backFromServer.ConnectionContext.Password = "password";



            backToServer.ConnectionContext.LoginSecure = false;
            backToServer.ConnectionContext.Login = "username";
            backToServer.ConnectionContext.Password = "password";


            Database backFromDb = new Database();
            backFromDb = backFromServer.Databases["databasesource"];

            Database backToDb = new Database();
            backToDb = backToServer.Databases["databasedest"];

            EventLog.WriteEntry(eventLogSource,"Loading databases successful!", EventLogEntryType.Information);

            Transfer dataTransfer = new Transfer(backFromDb);
            dataTransfer.CopyAllTables = true;
            dataTransfer.CopyAllObjects = false;
            dataTransfer.CopyData = true;
            dataTransfer.CopyAllUserDefinedDataTypes = true;
            dataTransfer.CopyAllStoredProcedures = false;

            dataTransfer.DropDestinationObjectsFirst = true;

            dataTransfer.Options.WithDependencies = false;

            dataTransfer.DestinationServer = backToServer.Name;
            dataTransfer.DestinationDatabase = backToDb.Name;
            dataTransfer.DestinationLoginSecure = false;
            dataTransfer.DestinationLogin = "username";
            dataTransfer.DestinationPassword = "password";


            EventLog.WriteEntry(eventLogSource,"Transfer configuration successful, starting to transfer!", EventLogEntryType.Information);

            dataTransfer.TransferData();//here causes the error

            EventLog.WriteEntry(eventLogSource, "Transfer successful!", EventLogEntryType.Information);
```

I managed to find a solution
so the app does this:
step 1. backup the database into a .bak file by using the Backup class

```
 Server backFromServer = new Server(@"server");
            backFromServer.ConnectionContext.LoginSecure = false;
            backFromServer.ConnectionContext.Login = "un";
            backFromServer.ConnectionContext.Password = "psd";
            Database backFromDb = new Database();
            backFromDb = backFromServer.Databases["dbname"];

            Backup bkpDatabase = new Backup();
            bkpDatabase.Action = BackupActionType.Database;
            bkpDatabase.Database = backFromDb.Name;
            bkpDatabase.Incremental = false;
            bkpDatabase.LogTruncation = BackupTruncateLogType.Truncate;
            bkpDatabase.Initialize = true;

            BackupDeviceItem bkpDevice = new BackupDeviceItem(@"c:\backup.bak", DeviceType.File);

            bkpDatabase.Devices.Add(bkpDevice);
            bkpDatabase.SqlBackup(backFromServer);

            EventLog.WriteEntry(eventLogSource, "Create database backup file successful!", EventLogEntryType.Information);
```

step 2. Since the file is in the source server, download the file.
step 3. restore the database by using t-sql.
step 4. fire up a scheduled task that runs the app on daily basis.
  here is the t-sql script:
USE master
ALTER DATABASE [DBName] SET Single_User WITH Rollback Immediate
RESTORE DATABASE [DBName] FROM DISK = N'filepath' WITH REPLACE, FILE = 1,  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
ALTER DATABASE [DBName] SET Multi_User

Comment: Why would you use this vs the native SQL Server backup/restore tools?

Comment: I'm not familiar to Sql server backup/restore tool, what I'm trying to accomplish here is to backup the particular database on daily basis to another remote server. would sql server backup/restore tool satisfy the need?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what the backup/restore features are there for. If you think about it you are using the same Integration Service "objects" as they do. You are essentially writing a new front end for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a sql job that does the, well, the job by doing backup & restore, log shipping, SQL Replication, etc. Doesn't sound like a problem you want to solve through an app running daily but a sql job instead, which will be more reliable, get monitoring, diagnostics for free, not to mention that you will need to run your app with high privileges, which is in itself a bad practice and a call for trouble.

Comment: Yes, thank for the help.Ill look into this. but still I'm puzzled by the issue because when I run the code locally, it works, but when I upload it to the server where it's supposed to reside in, it gives that error, given that the ssis is installed and full permissions are granted to the logins, ⊙ˍ⊙?

Answer (score 3):

Could you possibly create a sql command object with the following command?

```
BACKUP DATABASE DatabaseName
TO DISK = 'path\DatabaseName_Backup.bak'
WITH FORMAT, COPY_ONLY
```

and then restore using

```
RESTORE DATABASE SomeDatabase
  FROM DISK = 'path\DatabaseName_Backup.bak' 
  WITH FILE=1, 
    NORECOVERY;
```

Comment: thanks divi, you've made a good point, if automating it is possible then we have a great solution

Comment: I haven't really tried this, but I do run these commands manually as we don't have direct access to run backup commands on the server database. Happy to help

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( { } ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

Does the box you're **running** the application on have IS installed?

Comment: What is the security context in which your application runs? Try adding it to the administrator's group, and see if that fixes it. Also, OMG Ponies above is right...you ought to take a look at the backup restore / replication stuff.

Comment: database replication...hm..sounds like a db admin's job, as the nature of being a programmer I'm instinctively leaning to do this job programmatically..

Comment: @walter - definitely. I've spent much of my career being a poor man's dba.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Sql Server Management Objects:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.aspx

Using the scripter class you can script the entire database, then run that script.